# Why do the IDs are repeating in my HABTM association?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using the last version of cake php 2.3.2.
I have three tables:

1. domains
2. keywords
3. domains_keywords

Domain model has this association:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Keyword' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'Keyword',
            'joinTable'              => 'domains_keywords',
            'foreignKey'             => 'domain_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'keyword_id',
            'unique'                 => 'keepExisting'
        )
);
```

Keyword model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Domain' =>
        array(
            'className'              => 'Domain',
            'joinTable'              => 'domains_keywords',
            'foreignKey'             => 'keyword_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'domain_id',
            'unique'                 => 'keepExisting'
        )
);
```

as you can see i used **KeepExisting**

Now, I am adding reconds inside this table in this manner:

```
$this->Domain->DomainsKeyword->save(
                array(
                    'domain_id'  => $domain_id,
                    'keyword_id' => $key_id
                )
            )
```

the saving is fine but If i do it again and again the records are repeating in my database. Why? I used keepexisting... I do not want the same record more than one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't how keepexisting is supposed to work by keeping existing associations ? I think you have to use

```
 'unique' => 'true'
```

To get what you want.

Comment: i would use boolean `true` instead of string `'true'`

Comment: don't you need to domain_keywords model?